# REST call rounding up the Long date to the nearest second

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am setting up a date object using Java's `eventDate = new Date(Long)`. Then passing this value over REST using `@queryParam("eventDate") Date eventDate`. The Long value of the date before I passing through the REST was 1417546618**268**. However, the Long value of the date received was 1417546618**000**. Can anyone please let me know if this is the correct behavior? Or any other workaround except changing the method signature to Long.

Comment: How did you validate this? I don't think there is something like auto rounding in rest service.

Comment: I logged the values before and after the REST call.

Comment: If you are passing a long you should receive a long then use the long to re-create the date.

Comment: Why don't you want to change the method signature to long?

Comment: We are modifying the previously written API. Not many users will be happy if I change the method signature. They survived with this issue one so far, but I am trying to correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a suggestion response, you can use String. Send the long as String, receive it as a String, and then parse it with Long.parseLong(...) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I guess I will go with modifying the signature.